# What is the structure of the testing data file in libsvm?

Tags: classification, libsvm

According to the README file:

> The format of training and testing data file is:
>
> label index1:value1 index2:value2...

My training file would be something like this:

```
1 1:120 2:29925 3:151 ... # values belonging to class 1
2 1:66 2:5577 3:114 ...   # values belonging to class 2
3 1:249 2:77 3:73 ...     # values belonging to class 3
```

The first column says to which class the values belongs.
I don't get why should I put the *label* column in the testing file too: if the *label* says to which class the values should belong, how can I know in advance to which class they belong?

My testing file is as follows:

```
1:118 2:114 3:110 ...
1:260 2:277 3:1422 ...
```

If I have to put a label field in my testing file, what value should it have?

Comment: You can give any value. The values are used for LIBSVM's self-reported accuracy, but it's not used to predict in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give any value. The values are used for LIBSVM's self-reported accuracy, but it's not used to predict in any way.